# php Creating a unique file for download

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am trying to create a page where users can download a route from that they made. Now I am putting the route in a gpx file (made with PHP), saved on the server. And using JS to download the file.

If I'm correct, when there are multiple users at the same time; this will give problems and get their routes mixed up.

My question is how can I save their route temporarely so that it can be downloaded afterwards, without getting things mixed up. This should be possible without a user login.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just serve up the gpx file on request using http headers, I've did something simular ages ago for pdf and doc files.

```
<?php
// your logic to get the correct gpx data goes here

header("Content-type: application/gpx+xml");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=route.gpx");

echo "<xml>";
// your gpx data here
echo "</xml>";
```

This way you can use the same link for all users but each of them would get their unique file generated on-the-fly

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a file name that'll be different from other requests running concurrently:

```
$filename = uniqid('route.') . '.gpx';
```

Comment: be a little careful with this on heavily trafficked sites

Comment: Dagon is right.  If the consequences of a collision are highly negative, then another strategy must be found.  If 2 requests run in the same microsecond (millionth of a sec), they could get the same `uniqid`.  If it's the usual case of "huh, that's weird; let me reload; there that's better" happening once every 10 years, then `uniqid` is good enough.

Comment: just an idea: `$filename = 'route'.md5(uniqid() .rand()). '.gpx';` it would have to be a *VERY* heavily trafficked site for that to either be a clash.

Comment: Good idea but you probably would want to use a cryptographic level random function instead of `rand` (which, i wouldn't be surprised if it used microtime just like `uniqid` so that 2 requests running in the same microsecond get the same `rand`).  And maybe provide inputs unique to the request such as user-agent, ip-address, etc.

Comment: perhaps `random_int()` but only in php7, probably beyond the code of the OP's requirements ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply  use a hash/checksum of the route (gpx/xml-string)